# How to listen to external variable changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, axios

Hope you're doing well :)

I've an "auth.js" file, with an aysnc function to get the **userId** and then store it in session storage. Here it is:

```
export let userId = sessionStorage.getItem("userId");

const getUserId = async () => {
  if (token) {
    await axios
      .get(`${baseURL}/auth/user`, {
        headers: {
          authorization: token
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        const { data } = response;
        return sessionStorage.setItem("userId", data.userId);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        return undefined;
      });
  }
};
getUserId();
```

Then I access this variable in all components that need it, in order to make other requests. Example in App.js:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getActiveGames();
    if (token && userId) {
      getCart();
      getWallet();
      getWalletPayments();
    }
  }, []);
```

The problem is that, in the first render, the **userId comes null** (obviously) and I'm trying different ways to update or even re-render, in order to get the updated value, but nothing seems to work.
I know there's somehow a basic solution for this, but I just can't figure it out.

It would be awesome if you could help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Option 1
:

If you want to know when userId is filled in sessionStorage:

1. Add `userId` in your component state.
2. Listen for the `storage` event. See [StorageEvent](http://StorageEvent)
3. Add userId as dependency in `useEffect`.

```
const getUserId = ()=> sessionStorage.getItem("userId");
const [userId, setUserId] = useState(getUserId());
    
useEffect(() => {
  const storage = (event) => {
    if(event.originalEvent.storageArea===sessionStorage){
       const data = getUserId();
       if(data) setUserId(data);
    } 
  };
  window.addEventListener("storage", storage);
   
  return ()=> window.removeEventListener("storage", storage)
}, []);
    
useEffect(() => {
  getActiveGames();
  if (token && userId) {
     getCart();
     getWallet();
     getWalletPayments();
  }
}, [userId]);
```

#### Option 2:

You can manage the `userId` using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

1. In `getUserId` return `data.userId`.

```
const UserContext = React.createContext();

const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(()=> {
    getUserId()
     .then(user => setUserId(user));
  }, []);

  return <UserContext.Provider value={userId}>
          {children}
         </UserContext.Provider>
}
```

In you App.js

```
return (<UserProvider>
    ...
</UserProvider)
```

Using userId from any component in your app:

```
 const userId = useContext(UserContext);

 useEffect(() => {
    getActiveGames();
    if (token && userId) {
       getCart();
       getWallet();
       getWalletPayments();
    }
 }, [userId]);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Clean and descriptive. It worked :D Be safe

Answer (score 1):

i think you can work with sates use a state manager like **redux** or **contex api** to update the state userId for exemple:

```
.then(function (response) {
        const { data } = response;
// here you set your state (userId = data.userId)
        return sessionStorage.setItem("userId", data.userId);
      })
```

i hope it will works for you